# Complex declarations

Tags: c, declaration

How do I interpret complex declarations like:

```
int * (* (*fp1) (int) ) [10]; ---> declaration 1
int *( *( *[5])())(); --------> declaration 2
```

Is there any rule that should be followed to understand the above declarations?

Comment: `int *( *( *[5])())();` <- where is the variable name in that declaration ?

Comment: Although i wont agree: Such declarations are one of the reasons, why some people fear and hate C and even more C++.

Comment: @REDSOFTADAIR No, people **makes the simple one complex**. **Why do you need to read the declarations out aloud?** You only need to know how to use it, and it is written in the declaration: `*(*(*fp1) (5)) [0]` is an `int`, and `*(*(*fp1) (7)) [9]`  too. About **C++**, I have to say this is not even a thing compared to the thousands of unnatural inconsistence designs in C++. You can see linus, stallman and knuth's words.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a great article about how to read complex declarations in C: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/complex_declarations.aspx

It helped me a lot!

Especially - You should read "The right rule" section. Here quote:

> int * (* (*fp1) (int) ) [10];
> This can be interpreted as follows:
>
> 1. Start from the variable name -------------------------- fp1
> 2. Nothing to right but ) so go left to find * -------------- is a pointer
> 3. Jump out of parentheses and encounter (int) --------- to a
>    function that takes an int as argument
> 4. Go left, find * ---------------------------------------- and returns a pointer
> 5. Jump put of parentheses, go right and hit [10] -------- to an array of
>    10
> 6. Go left find * ----------------------------------------- pointers to
> 7. Go left again, find int -------------------------------- ints.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`cdecl`](http://www.cdecl.org/)`*`:

```
cdecl> explain int *( *( *a[5])())();
 declare a as array 5 of pointer to function
 returning pointer to function returning pointer to int
cdecl> explain int * (* (*fp1) (int) ) [10];
 declare fp1 as pointer to function (int) returning
 pointer to array 10 of pointer to int
```

`*`Linked is a website that uses this command line tool in the backend.

Answer (score 6):

I've learned the following method long ago:

> Start from the type identifier (or the inner parenthesis) and move following a spiral taking the element at right first

In case of

```
 int * (* (*fp1) (int) ) [10];
```

You can say:

- fp1 is a (nothing on the right so move left)
- pointer to (move out of the inner parenthesis
- a function taking int as agument (the 1st on the right)
- and returns a pointer to (exit from parenthesis)
- an array of 10 elements of type
- pointer to (nothing left on the right)
- int

Resulting in:

> fp1 is a pointer to a function taking an int and returning a pointer to an array of 10 pointers to int

Drawing the actual spiral (in you your mind, at least) helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

For solving these complicated declarations, the rule you need to keep in mind is that the precedence of function-call operator () and array subscript operator [] is higher than dereference operator *. Obviously, parenthesis ( ) can be used to override these precedences.

Now, work out your declaration from the middle, which means from the identifier name.

> int * (* (*fp1) (int) ) [10]; --->declaration 1

Based on the precedences rule mentioned above, you can easily understand it by breaking down the declaration as

fp1 * (int) * [10] * int

and read it directly from left-to-right in English as
"fp1 is a pointer to a function accepting an int & returning a pointer to an array [10] of pointers to int". Note that the declaration is broken this way only to help understand it manually. The compiler need NOT parse it this way.

Similarly,

> int *( *( *[5])())(); -------->declaration 2

is broken as

[5] * () * () * int

So, it declares "an array [5] of type pointers to function () which returns a pointer to a function () which in turn returns a pointer to int".

Answer (score 3):

Start with the leftmost identifier and work your way out, remembering that absent any explicit grouping `[]` and `()` bind before `*`, e.g:

```
    *a[]                 -- is an array of pointer
  (*a)[]                 -- is a pointer to an array
    *f()                 -- is a function returning pointer
  (*f)()                 -- is a pointer to a function
```

Thus, we read `int *(*(*fp1)(int))[10]` as:

```
         fp1                     -- fp1
        *fp1                     -- is a pointer
       (*fp1)(int)               -- to a function
                                      taking an int parameter
      *(*fp1)(int)               -- returning a pointer
     (*(*fp1)(int))[10]          -- to a 10-element array
    *(*(*fp1)(int))[10]          -- of pointer 
int *(*(*fp1)(int))[10]          -- to int
```

The declaration `int *(*(*[5])())()` presents a bit of a challenge since there's no identifier; you typically see this in function declarations where a parameter is of that type:

```
void foo(int *(*(*[5])())(), double);
```

It's the same principle as the unnamed `int` parameter in the declaration of `fp1`.  The array gives us the clue, you can also look for the leftmost inner grouping of parentheses.

```
                         -- unnamed
         [5]             -- is a 5-element array ([] binds before *)
        *[5]             -- of pointers
       (*[5])()          -- to functions
      *(*[5])()          -- returning pointers
     (*(*[5])())()       -- to functions
    *(*(*[5])())()       -- returning pointers
int *(*(*[5])())()       -- to int
```

Answer (score 3):

The clockwise/spiral:

```
* http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know this method had a name!

Answer (score 1):

**No, you don't need to read it loud with complex steps like "clockwise/spiral rule" and "the right rule". Why should you? You only need to know how to use it!** Don't make the simple one complex.

C declarations in fact work in a **simple** rule: **declare as how would be used**.

Consider the code you gives out:

```c
int * (* (*fp1) (int) ) [10]; ---> declaration 1
int *( *( *[5])())(); --------> declaration 2
```

For the first declaration, this means that `*(*(*fp1)(int))[int]` is an `int`. And that's it.

For example, you know that `*(*(*fp1)(5))[0]` is an int, and `*(*(*fp1)(2))[9]` is an int too.

And The second declaration is incomplete. Even gcc won't know what you want to convey.