# How to understand these complicated pointer declarations?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Complex Declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893013/complex-declarations)

Can someone help me to break this down, and help me to understand?

```
1) char *(*(*a[N])( ))( );

2) char (* (*x[3]) ( ))[5];

3) char (*(*f( ))[ ]) ( );
```

Comment: please search SO: similar questions asked many, many times...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: There are some concepts, which might not be clear, especially if it relates to pointers, and FYI..i am a developer with  5 years of industry experience, and work for a electronics company whose name, every little child in the corner of the globe knows

Comment: my previous comment still stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The golden rule is. just use http://cdecl.org/:

1. `declare a as array 5 of pointer to function returning pointer to function returning pointer to char` (I replaced `N` with `5`)
2. `declare x as array 3 of pointer to function returning pointer to array 5 of char`
3. `declare f as function returning pointer to array of pointer to function returning char`

To understand how to interpret them yourself, this is a very good explanation from MSDN: [*Interpreting More Complex Declarators*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x82y1z4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx/).

Comment: If you change the `N` in 1 to a number, you get

> declare a as array 1 of pointer to function returning pointer to function returning pointer to char

Comment: @glglgl: Good spot.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Oli: Thanks for the link and the explanation, it was a good one.

Comment: @Oli: Completely understood now, thanks. I think now i can interpret any such declarations.