# C Deciphering declarations

Tags: c, encryption

Ok, this was a bit too much for me. How do you read these declarations?

```
char *(*(**myCBT[][10])())[];
```

Please note: I'm not specifically asking for this example but for a general rule of thumb if a beginner like me faces a tough puzzle like this.

Comment: http://www.cdecl.org/ Such declarations are a bit much for everyone. I doubt anyone can find a decent example where you would need that.

Comment: See e.g. http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html for "right-to-left" rule.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex Declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893013/complex-declarations)

Comment: @cnicutar: not as trouble as this one but signal(3) had a tricky declaration to many people, these days it's typedef'ed (at least here in BSDs).

Comment: @sidyll The declaration for a signal handler is short and sweet compared to an `array of arrays of pointers to pointers to functions`.

Comment: @cnicutar, for sure. I said that it's not that difficult, but its just a more real world example on where/how more complex declarations can be used.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use David Anderson's **[Clock wise spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)** for reading such notations.

Answer (score 1):

From [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/):

> declare myCBT as array of array 10 of pointer to pointer to function returning pointer to array of pointer to char

Comment: Is there a similar site for decoding that Pseudoenglish into English? :)

Comment: @razlebe It's already nicely explained. C declarations are read boustrophedonically.

Comment: @sidyll: <reproachful>I had to look that up!</reproachful>

Comment: @Rudy haha, now I'm wondering if we have one of these in German, though it's sometimes hard to find it even in English definition dictionaries. EDIT: Yep, boustrophedon > bustrophedon

Comment: I have never heard it in German either, and I live in Germany. <g>