# Couln't someone explain the grammar of typedef once and for all?

Tags: c++, typedef

I know how to declare aliases for simple types, like class types, primitive types and, say, pointers to functions returning the value of that types. Actually:

```
typedef int T; //T := int
typedef int* T; // T := int*
typedef int (*T)() //T := int (*)(). OK, but it's a bit unclear to me. 
                   //Seems a little bit confused
typedef int (*T[])() // T := array of int(*)(). Totally confused. What the hell is going on?
```

I can't understand how the compiler should parse such typedef declarations. Maybe someone can explain on the simple example that I cited? I know, that `c++` introduced alias decalrtion as follows:

```
using T = int*;
```

It could be more readable, but now I'm interested in only typedef decalration.

Comment: Typedefs essentially mirror the grammar for variable declarations.

Comment: Just ignore the T in the typedef and replace it with the variable name that you are defining

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth And...? Don't see how it can help me to understand

Comment: There are countless resources (and SO posts) that describe how to interpret complex variable declarations.  e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893013/complex-declarations

Comment: @EdHeal Ok, how can I ignore T in the last example? I don't even know how to write such a declarator.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: The point is that this is not a `typedef`-specific topic. You have the same hard-to-understand syntax if you directly declare objects. For example `int (*my_ptr[])();`

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*T[]%29%28%29) can be a handy tool to figure these sorts of things out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grammar of a `typedef` is exactly the same as that of a variable
declaration; the only difference is that the name being declared becomes
an alias for the type, rather than an object, reference or function.

Note that `typedef` is part of the *decl-specifier-seq* of the
declaration; a full declaration consists of three parts: an
*attribute-specifier-seq* (new to C++11), a *decl-specifier-seq*, and an
*init-declarator-list*, in that order.  All parts may in principle be
empty, but only for certain types of declarations; in the case of a
`typedef`, for example, only the *attribute-specifier-seq* may be empty.
To understand a declaration, you have to first break it down into the
three parts: the *attribute-specifier-seq* is easy: it will always be
within `[[...]]` and you won't see it too often, since it is very new,
and only for special uses.  We'll ignore it for now.  The
*decl-specifier-seq* is a sequence of keywords or symbols which name a
type (although there are special cases after some keywords, like
`struct` or `enum`); just collect all of the symbols until you encounter
something which isn't a keyword or a type.  `typedef` included.  Order
here isn't important, so:

```
int typedef const CI;
```

would be perfectly legal, although certainly not typical.  If the
keyword `typedef` is present, the declaration is a `typedef` (which
means that some other keywords, like `extern` or `static`, aren't
allowed).  The *decl-specifier* gives the final type in an English
expression of the type.

Everything that follows is part of the *init-declarator-seq* which is a
comma separated list of *init-declarator*.  A `typedef` requires at
least one *init-declarator*, and in fact, doesn't allow the init part,
so it is just a *declarator* (but there can in fact be several, although
Microsoft is the only ones I know that go in for this bit of
obfuscation).  Each declarator is basically an expression, with
the operators on the right (`()` and `[]`) having precedence over the
operators on the left (`*` and `&`), and parentheses being used to
modify the precedence.  So if you have something like `(&ra)[10]`, `ra`
is a reference to an array[10] of... what:w
ever type is specified by the
*decl-specified*.  Or where precedence is not given by parentheses:
`*ra[10]` is an array[10] of pointers to...

Answer (score 2):

`typedef`s follow the same rule as variable declarations, so I will first cover these. The intended principle is: if you type the declaration as an expression, you will get the type. So let's analyse this variable:

```
int (*a[])();
```

Now we proceed step by step:

Typing `(*a[42])()` gives an `int`. Substitute `x1` for `(*a[42])`. `x1()` is of type `int`, so clearly `x1` (which is `(*a[42])`) is a function taking no parameters and returning an `int`.

Therefore, `a[42]` must be a pointer to a "function taking no parameters and returning an `int`."

Therefore, `a` must be an array of "pointers to a function taking no parameters and returning an `int`."

With typedefs, the only difference is that instead of the variable `a`, we're talking about its *type*. So `typedef int (*T[])();` means:

> `T` is the type a variable `a` would have if it were declared as `int (*a[])();`

So in your case, `T` is "an array of pointers to function-taking-no-parameter-and-returning-`int`."

Comment: The principle is... that everything is historically conditioned.  The original idea was that the declaration mirrors the expression to use the variable; that more or less went out the window when `typedef` was introduced, and even more so with `const` and `volatile`.  (`int (*const a)[10];`, for example.)  And of course, definitions for classes don't obey the rule at all, and references also mess it up.  The _declarator_ is a sort of expression, however, and is best described as one, but the relationship with use is tenuous at best.

Comment: @JamesKanze OK, I've weakened the claim of what the principle is. But I still think this is a sensible way to learn to parse these declarations, even if it doesn't fully cover everything. Once get the hang of it, you can work out the special cases easily.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand how the compiler should parse such typedef declarations.

Since this seemed to be a main topic of concern I decided to add an important note regarding the higher-level overview of how this is possible.

Since there is now context in the language you need to have information available about both the syntax and the semantics of the language when parsing.

In your example the original solution used [the lex hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_lexer_hack), which is the actual name for the method that C++ compiler designers implemented to solve the problem of the language no longer being context-free due to the *typedef* token. The basic idea of this 'hack' is to have an additional backchannel from the semantic analyzer to the lexer to provide the needed context.

There are also other ways to solve the problem of parsing context-sensitive grammars such has *lexerless parsing*.