# What is the difference between int *[5] and int (*)[5] in C?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I am trying to understand the difference between `int *[5]` and `int (*)[5]` 
and my simple code is as below.

```
int main()
{
    int a[5] = {10,11,12,13,14};
    int *ptr[5];
    ptr = &a;
}
```

---

- What is the difference between `int *[5]` and `int (*)[5]` in C?

Comment: Maybe that would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893013/complex-declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int a[5]` - a is an array of 5 int.

`int (*a)[5]` - a is a pointer to an array of 5 int.

`int a[5][4]` - a is an mulitdimensional array with 5 dimensions of 4 int.

`int *a[5]` - a is an array of 5 int pointers.

Comment: `mulitdimensional array with 5 dimensions of 4 int` does not make sense. `a` is a 5×4 array of `int`s, simply. Or, precisely, `a` is an array of 5 objects, each of which is an array of 4 `int`s.